# What quote does this rebus represent?

Tags: rebus

The accepted answer will be the first to include the correct quote, the author, and explain each part of the rebus. Most importantly, have fun!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is a long one!

Comment: Is that a Berserker (or some other Uruk-hai) in the second line, by any chance?

Comment: @randal'thor maybe it is! all of it is straight-forward. there aren't any tricks in it, I don't think. Just a good ole rebus for the fun of it.

Comment: I always thought it was SMILIES and not SMILEYS...

Comment: Great puzzle btw! I enjoyed solving it :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

> "What the world needs is more geniuses with humility, there are so few of us left." - Oscar Levant

Explanation:

> (Buckwheat - bucket) + (thigh - high) = *Wha* + *t* = **What**
>
> (torch - orc) + (caret - cart) = *th* + *e* = **the**
>
> (woman - man) + (pearl - pea) + (drain - rain) = *wo* + *rl* + *d* = **world**
>
> (miner - mir) + (echidnas - china) = *ne* + *eds* = **needs**
>
> (pennies - penne) = **is**
>
> (mowing - wing) + (freight - fight) = *mo* + *re* = **more**
>
> (halogens - halos) + (helium - helm) + (switches - witch) = *gen* + *iu* + *ses* = **geniuses**
>
> (weights - eights) + (filthy - fly) = *w* + *ith* = **with**
>
> (shoulder - solder) + (mildew - dew) + (bandit - band) + (smileys + smiles) = *hu* + *mil* + *it* + *y* = **humility**
>
> (matches - mace) + (bread - brad) + (grapes - gaps) = *th* + *e* + *re* = **there**
>
> (minarets - mints) = **are**
>
> (bison - bin) = **so**
>
> (frame - ram) + (wax - ax) = *fe* + *w* = **few**
>
> (orange - range) + (face - ace) = *o* + *f* = **of**
>
> (boulders - bolder) = **us**
>
> (bugle - bug) + (forest - ores) = *le* + *ft* = **left**

Great quote!

Comment: Damn, ninja'd! As I feared. +1 :-)

Comment: You were on the right track, though! Sorry for stealing it right from under you!

Answer (score 2):

First line:

> (BUCKWHEAT<sup>3</sup> - BUCKET) + (THIGH - HIGH) = WHAT<sup>2</sup>

Second line:

> (TORCH - ORC) + (CARET - CART) = THE

Third line:

> (WOMAN - MAN) + (PEARL - PEA)<sup>1</sup> + (DRAIN - RAIN) = WORLD

Fourth line:

> (MINER - MIR<sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>) +(ECHIDNAS - CHINA) = NEEDS

Fifth line:

> (PENNIES - PENNE) = IS

Sixth line:

> (MOWING - WING) + (FREIGHT - FIGHT) = MORE<sup>1</sup>

Seventh line:

> (HALOGEN - HALO) + (HELIUM - HELM)<sup>2</sup> + (SWITCHES - WITCH) = GENIUSES

Eighth line:

> (WEIGHTS - EIGHTS) + (FILTHY - FLY) = WITH

Ninth line:

> (SHOULDER - SOLDER) + (MILDEW - DEW) + (BANDIT - BAND) + (SMILEYS - SMILES) = HUMILITY

Tenth line:

> (MATCHES - MACES) + (BREAD - BRAD<sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>) + (GRAPES - GAPS) = THERE

Eleventh line:

> (MINARETS - MINTS) = ARE; (BISON - BIN)<sup>2</sup> = SO

Twelfth line:

> (FRAME - RAM) + (WAX - AX) = FEW

Thirteenth line:

> (ORANGE - RANGE) + (FACE - ACE) = OF

Fourteenth line:

> (BOULDERS - BOLDER) = US<sup>2</sup>

Fifteenth and last line:

> (BUGLE - BUG) + (FOREST - ORES) = LEFT

Full answer:

> WHAT THE WORLD NEEDS IS MORE GENIUSES WITH HUMILITY; THERE ARE SO FEW OF US LEFT

which is a quote from

> Oscar Levant<sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to Eli!
<sup>2</sup> I'd seen the quote in Josh's answer (but not his explanations) when I solved this clue.
<sup>3</sup> Had to Google this one! TIL a new word :-)

Comment: no rearranging needed. i didn't think rebuses allowed for that anyway. thats a late dinner at 10pm!

Comment: Third line = woman - man + pearl - pea + drain - rain = world

Comment: Six line = mowing - wing + freight - fight = more

Comment: @JLee Now that I've been ninja'd and you've accepted the other answer, any point in me finishing this off?

Comment: I'm gonna +1 you. you put lots of effort into it, and got most of it.

Comment: I would've answered your question in the comments, but i fell asleep and just woke up.

Comment: @JLee Thanks - did you have to laugh as you +1'ed? :-)

Comment: I +1'd, too, because JLee is right - it IS a lot of effort. If you haven't peeked at my explanation, you should try to finish it!

Comment: @Josh A lot of effort to solve, but REALLY a lot of effort to make. I worked on that thing all week on and off! Nice job both of you.

Comment: @Josh I have now peeked at the quote, which will probably make it easier for me, but haven't read the explanation. Is it fair play to finish it when I know the quote?

Comment: @randal'thor If it's fun for you, then by all means finish it.

Comment: @rand: Knowing the quote is only half the battle! Try to make the rebus fit is the other half! :P

Comment: Mir is correct. It's the name of the satellite. :D

Comment: @Josh, I just updated a few things I had forgotten to do earlier when making it. I pointed to the correct part of the candle, and I removed the answer from the graph and inserted a question mark. Nice job figuring these out when they weren't clear.